# Is there a way to hide the scroll indicators in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a use case where those indicators disturb the user interaction. Can I subclass and override a method or do something similar to remove the scroll indicators from the scroll view?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Set the `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` and `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` properties of the `UIScrollView` to `NO`.

```
[tableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

[Documentation - UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview?language=objc)

Comment: As learnt from Docs,you can even use it for scrollview directly!
[scrollview setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
Thanks to @retainCount

Comment: As of iOS 11, this should be called in viewWillAppear,  it doesn't work if called in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 72):

**//For UITableView - Objective-C**

```
tbl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
tbl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

**//For UITableView - SWIFT 3.0**

```
tbl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
tbl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

**//For UIScrollView - Objective-C**

```
scrl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

**//For UIScrollView - SWIFT**

```
scrl.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scrl.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

**Change from XIB or storyboard**

[image]

Comment: tableView also has checkboxes for this - I'm working with xCode 11

Answer (score 21):

For those looking to do this in Swift.

```
self.tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score 11):

For UIScrollView in Swift

```
scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score 7):

`Swift 3.0` extension for `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`:

```
import Foundation

extension UIScrollView {
    func hideIndicators() {
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These are your `UITableView` scrolling properties:

```
[YourTableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[YourTableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

These are your `UIScrollView` scrolling properties:

```
[YourScroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[YourScroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

No answers have worked for me because the focus ring of indicators is shown every time but I solve my problem via `NSStoryboard`.

NSCollectionView have a diagram;

`Scroll View - Collection View then Clip View then Scroller (vertical) & Scroller (Horizontal)`

[image]

Click any Scroller object then in `Attributes Inspector` set `Focus Ring` property to `None`. If you have not set it you can have a problem when users change the `Appearance` between `Dark` and `Light`.